# Text appears hazy on using translateZ ?

Tags: css

I was creating a rotating cube kind of effect but i don't understand why in any of the 3 sides, the text is not clear, it appears hazy. I want to make the text clear, you dont need the read the whole code, only inside the `#cube` part.

```css
#container {
    width: 500px;
 height: 600px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100px;
 left: 100px;
 perspective: 1500px;
 perspective-origin: 50% 300px;
}
#cube {
 position: absolute;
 top: 60px;
 left: 150px;
 transition: transform 0.5s;
 transform-origin: 100px 50%;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#cube div {
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
 height: 400px;
 background: linear-gradient(60deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.8));
 border: 1px solid black;
}
#hobbies {
 transform: rotateY(-60deg) translateZ(173px);
}
#about {
 transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(173px);
}
#interests {
 transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(173px);
}
input[type=radio] {
 display: none;
}
label {
 background-color: orange;
 padding: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 520px;
 width: 70px;
 text-align: center;
}
label:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}
label[for=left] {
 left: 100px;
}
label[for=front] {
 left: 200px;
}
label[for=right] {
 left: 300px;
}
#left:checked ~ #cube{
 transform: rotateY(60deg);
}
#front:checked ~ #cube{
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
#right:checked ~ #cube{
 transform: rotateY(-60deg);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="container">
   <input type="radio" name="glass"  id="left"><label for="left">Hobbies</label>
      <input type="radio" name="glass"  id="front"><label for="front">About Me</label>
      <input type="radio" name="glass"  id="right"><label for="right">Interests</label>
      <div id="cube">   
        <div id="hobbies"><h1 style="color: black;">.....hobbies.....</h1></div>
          <div id="about">.....about me.....</div>
          <div id="interests">.....interests.....</div>
      </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using a decent font like arial? Please create a jsfiddle and we can check it how it looks like.

Comment: Tranform: translateZ causes antialiasing to use grayscale instead of subpixel. As far as I know there's no solution. Check out this article: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/antialiasing-101/#toc-cutting-to-the-chase